# How to edit a Portlet or Plugin in Liferay?

Tags: jsp, plugins, liferay, portlet

I downloaded a plugin and I would like to edit the visuals of it. Like change the width of some things so they look better. I believe I have to modify the JSPs of the Portlet or the Plugin but I am not quite sure if this is the right way. If it is, where do I find these JSP files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the core it would be a JSP-Hook (read the development guide about creating a hook). However, for a plugin it's slightly different. First of all, it's a WAR file, which is nothing else but a zip file, it should be easy to locate the jsps once you unzip the file. However, this will not be very maintenance-friendly. Instead, you might want to follow [Julio's instruction in the Liferay wiki](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugin+to+extend+a+plugin) and utilize ant and a slightly adjusted build process. This will neatly separate your changes from the underlying plugin

Comment: I downloaded the plugin through the Portal and I don't see the WAR file anywhere, shouldn't it be in the deploy folder?

Comment: If you get it from marketplace, you can also download it manually - go to https://www.liferay.com/marketplace, see your plugins, download. You'll get a lpkg file, which is actually a zip that contains the war file and some descriptors